# Single Word is out of Div in chrome but not on mozilla

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to make a circular div with a single letter in it. It worked fine on Ubuntu(16.04)-Mozilla, but now the text is out of div in Windows10-Chrome.[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hRDC.jpg)
Here is the code: HTML:

```
<div class="Try"><p style="font-family: Bungee; font-size: 8mm;">A</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.Try p,(some other Classes which works fine){
width: 10mm;
height: 10mm;
border-radius: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
display: block;
float: right;
bottom: 0;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
margin-right: 60mm;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SamX13/L1jtjznr/ <--- this is the code reproducing problem

Comment: Don't use `position:fixed`.

Comment: I want the element to be there even if someone scrolls the page. Removing position: fixed; will take away this property.

Comment: The you need to position the **parent** ...not the content.

Comment: I put your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/rbpo21m4/), but I  don't see many differences between OSes. You _are_ using the same font on both systems, aren't you?

Comment: Actually, there are 3 divs which are aligned vertically. (comes on bottom right corner). If I remove position: fixed; these elements shift to top right corner and become horizontal.  even if I add position: fixed to just .try instead of .try p these shifts to top left. I'm very confused, any help will be grateful.

Comment: @MrLister yes. A font from fonts.google.com

Comment: Can you post the real code then? And screenshots of the differences.

Comment: @MrLister I was assuming the the div was just a wrapper for the centered paragraph but it seems that this is not the case. Without an [MCVE] we're stuck.

Comment: @MrLister and Paulie please help! https://jsfiddle.net/SamX13/L1jtjznr/

Comment: There are hundred of questions & answers about centering on Stack Overflow. Figure that out **first**  and *then* worry about positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, the browsers seem to think that the line height of the Bungee font is higher than in Linux. I don't know what causes it, but the solution is to set the line height explicitly in the css.

```css
.try p, .abc p, .xyz p {
  width: 10mm;
  height: 10mm;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: 60mm;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 1cm;           /* new */
}

.try p {
  margin-bottom: 42mm;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.abc p {
  margin-bottom: 25mm;
}

.xyz p {
  margin-bottom: 8mm;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Permanent+Marker|Electrolize|Yellowtail" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="try">
  <p style="font-family: 'Bungee'; font-size: 8mm;">A</p>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <p style="font-family: 'Permanent Marker'; font-size: 8mm;">B</p>
</div>
<div class="xyz">
  <p style=" font-size: 8mm; font-family: 'Electrolize';">C</p>
</div>
```

(Note that I also reduced the bottom margins a bit to fit the whole thing in an unexpanded snippet. So don't copy everything back to your CSS, only the new line.)

Comment: Yes! It works. Very Thank you, Sir. For saving my day and my ambitious project. I'm indebted.